# Check all check boxes only in one table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple tables with rows of check boxes and want to perform a select all if the header check box is selected. I am trying to do this with jQuery without parsing or passing in the table id. Currently I am hitting all the check boxes when I select one header check box.

All checkboxes have the same class, but I am sure there is a way to do this by limiting the selection of check boxes to the table that the selected check box is in. I have this laid out in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/WMXgy/

```
checkBoxes = function (me) {

     $(".dpsPreCode").closest("table [type='checkbox']").each(function () {
         if (this.checked === false) {
             this.checked = true;
         } else {
             this.checked = false;
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the checkbox as `me`, so if you use that to find the closest table, it should work :

```
checkBoxes = function (me) {
    $(me).closest("table").find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(me).prop('checked', me.checked);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMXgy/3/)

Comment: That works perfectly. I knew I was just missing something simple. Thanks!